# How to specify hardware ram size for Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm creating an Android emulator with API level 27 and Android Studio always starts it with ~1.5gb of ram completely ignoring the amount of ram I specify in Configure Hardware Profile. I've tried setting ram 128, 256, 512, 1024 MB but the emulator always has ~1.5GB of ram when I check with:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys meminfo
...
Total RAM: 1,530,604K (status normal)
...
```

AVD shows the correct (what I specified) amount of ram (hw.ramSize) when I check the details of the emulator.

Why is the emulator ignoring my specified ram amount when I launch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android emulator (version 30.0.5 as of writing) appears to ignore `hw.ramSize` item in `config.ini` or the `-memory` option in the emulator command line. I managed to adjust the memory size of AVDs at the qemu level. The command I use is:

```
/opt/android-sdk/emulator/emulator @avdName -qemu -m 1204
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the ram of an already running emulator?

Comment: @Arthur I'm afraid not. I don't think Android supports advanced techniques like memory ballooning.